# C# test always return true even when test fails

Tags: c#, tdd, automated-tests

Before when I was running my tests I had set up my code to look like the following:

```csharp
private bool ValidateTestOne(EntityModel.MultiIndexEntities context)
{
    if (context.SearchDisplayViews.Count() != expectedSdvCount)
    {
        Assert.Fail("Search Display View count was different from what was expected");
    }

    if (sdv.VirtualID != expectedSdVirtualId)
    {
        Assert.Fail("Search Display View virtual id was different from what was expected");
    }

    if (sdv.EntityType != expectedSdvEntityType)
    {
        Assert.Fail("Search Display View entity type was different from what was expected");
    }

    return true;
}
```

This would also return the correct path telling me if a test passed or failed. Since then, and after some advice, I changed my code so it look like the following:

```csharp
private bool ValidateTestOne(EntityModel.MultiIndexEntites  context)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedEntityCount, context.Entities.Count(),
        "Entity Count was different from what was expected");

    return true;
}
```

My thinking on using the new `Assert.AreEqual`is that it would still return back true or false depending if it passed or failed. But now my test is always returning true because I have no way of working out if my test failed or not.

All this is determined by called the following line in my main test method:

```csharp
Assert.IsTrue(test4PassFail = ValidateTest("4.4"), "Test 4 ");
```

Is there a way I can ammend my new code to return true or false without having to revert back to my old code?

Comment: Are you using a testing framework, or your own in house suite?

Comment: I'm using what ever it is you get with visual studio.

Comment: Why does your test method has a return value?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing `return true;`, you could do `Assert.AreEqual(expectedEntityCount, context.Entities.Count()");`.

This would be your fail/pass. You don't need to do a return. But as it is, you're returning `true` all the time.

```
[TestClass]
public class Tests
{
     [TestMethod]
     private void ValidateTestOne(EntityModel.MultiIndexEntites  context)
     {
          Assert.AreEqual(expectedEntityCount, context.Entities.Count(), "Entity Count was different from what was expected");
     }
}
```

Comment: I just tried that but my test is still pass even though it has my error message in the output window.

Comment: Silly question, but did you delete the `return` statement?

Comment: yeah, commented it out. Method is now void

Comment: Added a code sample for you. It should look something similar to this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to follow the MSTest way of doing tests.  Your class needs to have the [TestClass] attribute, and your methods need [TestMethod].  The methods within the test class are all void.  Your methods are returning true regardless of the assertions.  VS allows you to add a test project and test classes to support your code.  It will add in the appropriate attributes for you.

```
[TestClass]
public class Tests
{
   [TestMethod]
   public void DriveInfoTest()
   {
       // set up
       DriveUnit uut = new DriveUnit();

       // run
       var result = uut.GetInfo();


      // verify
      Assert.IsNotNull(result, "Get Info did not return an object.");
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the first one you're always returning true because thats what you set it to return.

you should consider making them nested if else statements

```
private bool ValidateTestOne(EntityModel.MultiIndexEntities context)
  {
     if (context.SearchDisplayViews.Count() != expectedSdvCount)
        {
              Assert.Fail(" Search Display View count was different from what was expected");
//does it return true or false?
//return true or false

        } else if (sdv.VirtualID != expectedSdVirtualId){

             Assert.Fail(" Search Display View virtual id was different from what was expected");

//again true or false?

        } else if(sdv.EntityType != expectedSdvEntityType) {
           Assert.Fail(" Search Display View entity type was different from what was expected");
//true or false?

        }

  }
```